# Event every 5th day of mont (or 4th/3rd if it's weekend or holiday) using iCal

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

In Brazil my payday happen on every 5th day of month.

But if the 5th day is a saturday/sunday, then the payment will happen on the 4th day.

Same if 4th is saturday/sunday: then the payment will happen on 3rd day. And so on.

Is there any way to create a event that will work with Google Calendar and iCal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with iCalendar, at least as far as it concerns weekends.

Consider the following rule:

```
DTSTART;TZID=US-Eastern:20160505T000000
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3,4,5;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1
```

The rule is evaluated as follows:

- `FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3,4,5`: expand to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th day of each month
- `BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR`: filter by week day, retain only work days/remove weekend days
- `BYSETPOS=-1`: retain only the last day of the set

You can verify the result at http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/

Here are the [first 100 instances](http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/reaas?dtstart=20160505T000000&rrule=FREQ%3DMONTHLY%3BBYMONTHDAY%3D1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%3BBYDAY%3DMO%2CTU%2CWE%2CTH%2CFR%3BBYSETPOS%3D-1&skip=&max_instances=100&expansion_window_end=21000101T000000).

It's not possible to achieve that for holidays though.

---

**Update:**

It's actually sufficient to specify

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=3,4,5;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1
```

Since the weekend is at most 2 days long, payday must fall on one of the 3rd, 4th or 5th day of the month. Again, this does not take holidays into account.

Holidays always need special consideration. Not only does `RRULE` not support this kind of logic for arbitrary days, sometimes it's difficult or even impossible to express holidays by an RRULE themselves. In some countries certain holidays are always on a specific day, except when the days falls on a weekend, in which case the holiday is on the Friday before or the Monday after the weekend. Or consider the Easter date and holidays relative to the Easter date, they can't be expressed by an RRULE at all.
Not to forget that some holidays may change every now and then (like "King's days" or "Queen's days" in certain countries).

The best you can do is to manage these manually and add an RDATE and an EXDATE if payday would fall on a holiday according to the RRULE above.